# Discord.py bot stays active even after code is stopped

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot in python. At one point in coding the bot, it stopped updating, it kept using old code. Then I realized the bot never stopped. I kicked it and reinvited it, but the problem did not go away.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: How are you stopping the bot? Make sure you completely stop the Python process, not just ctrl+c or whatever.

Comment: @sytech how do i do so?

Comment: Depends on how you're running the bot and your operating system. If you're on Windows, task manager is an easy bet... note that Python may be running as a subprocess of your IDE if you run Python through your IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kicking will not fix it, it's a problem some code compliers may have, or just the concurrent running version is still running.

Editors like sublime can do this problem if the existing program has not been stopped.

This can be easily fixed by going back into Discord's developer portal and "regenerate token". After this, update with the same new token in your code with running the bot token. This will force terminate any builds running.

Comment: Preferably use a complier that cannot run multiple concurrent versions of a code. Or just always make sure to end the existing build before updating and running a new version

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, after about 30 seconds or so, the bot should stop

Comment: Its been going on for several hours now

Comment: Are you using a hosting service?

Comment: no, im still developing it on my computer

Comment: Try restarting your computer, or at least killing python from Task Manager id your on Windows